# On Cramér's theorem about roots of Zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Cramér proved the following theorem (see the announcement in [1] and [2]):

Consider the following function:

> $$V(z)=\sum_k e^{\rho_kz}$$

Where $\rho_k$ runs through non trivial zeta zeros with $Im(\rho_k) > 0$

Cramér proved $V(z)$ converges for $Im(z) > 0$ and has a singularity at the origin of the type $\frac{\log(z)}{(1-e^{-z})}$
by which it means that the function

> $$F(z) = 2πiV(z) -\frac{\log(z)}{(1-e^{-z})}$$

has a meromorphic continuation to all $\Bbb C$, with simple poles at the points $\pm πin$ where $n$ ranges over the integers, and at the points $\pm\log(p^m)$ where $p^m$ ranges over the
prime powers.

I have following questions

> 1. I'm wondering if $V(z)$ has alternate explicit expression ?
> 2. (Simpler) reference where I can study about this ? ( Other than Cramér’s paper itself)

**References**

[1] Harald Cramér, "[Sur les zéros de la fonction $\zeta(s)$](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3121p.f539)" (French), Comptes Rendus Hebdomadaires des Séances de l’Académie des Sciences, Paris, tome 168 (Janvier-Juin), 539-541 (1919),
[JFM 47.0289.02](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A47.0289.02).

[2] Harald Cramér, "[Studien über die Nullstellen der Riemannschen Zetafunktion](https://eudml.org/doc/167519)" (German), Math. Zeitschr. 4, 104-130 (1919), [JFM 47.0289.03](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A47.0289.03).

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thank you for an excellent edit!

Answer (score 8):

**Q1:** There is a functional relation for $V(z)$, but no "explicit expression" I know of.

**Q2:** Cramér's paper is from 1919, a modern and more extensive treatment is in [On Cramér's theorem for general Euler products with functional equation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01459509) (1993).